# How do I adjust V-brakes as the pads wear?

Tags: brakes, brake-pads, adjustment, wear

I have V-brakes and when the pads wear down, the brake needs adjustment.

Adjusting by undoing and tightening the cable is difficult, is there an easier way to adjust V-brakes to compensate for pad wear?

Comment: What problem do you have with barrel adjusters? I agree that initial alignment of the brake pads is a PITA.

Comment: They did come up with a better system, its called hydraulic disc brakes. There are hydraulic rim brakes, not sure if solving the adjustment problems was a goal of them though.

Comment: You can find a local bike commune, sometimes called bike repair café, where enthusiasts show and teach simple maintenance hands-on.

Comment: Andy, I think there is a good question in there so I have edited a little to bring that out, hope that's ok

Comment: @mattnz The TRP Hy/Rd will self-adjust, while the juihist ones do not. Those effectively have a barrel adjuster on the piston arm.

Comment: Hopefully folks come back and undo their downvotes after the @Swifty edits. This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 7):

The rim brakes on my last bike had a barrel adjuster that did what you ask.  My new bike has disk brakes and they self-adjust.

[image]
The barrel adjuster here is the black cylinder on the right-side.  The brake housing/cable pass through the middle.  To bring the pads closer to the rim, rotate the barrel adjuster so it comes out from the lever's body by a turn or two, and then tighten the thinner lock ring in the opposite direction against the body.  Check the rim still rotates freely between the pads.

Comment: I could use some more details. Your answer is lacking somewhat. @Ross Millikan

Comment: I didn't have to play with the pads on the old bike.  If I wanted to move them closer to the rim, I turned the barrel adjuster.  I rode the bike for five years, never replaced the pads, and never ran out of range on the adjuster.  That sounds like it answers what you are looking for.  The disk brakes need no adjustment until the pads are worn out.  That happened in a year and I am riding new ones.

Comment: @RossMillikan feel free to update if required.